# Programatically add an MvxSpinner using IAttributes from parent

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-custom-view

I have a custom view (`MyCustomView`), in which I would like to add `MvxSpinner` and some `TextView`'s. I would like to put all bindings on the custom view and pass them to the MvxSpinner, so I can integrate this new component in my application using the example below, using different bindings each time.

E.g.

in xml

```
<MyCustomView
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner_dark"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource StampTypes"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_dropdown_item" />
```

Now, in code I want to add an `MvxSpinner` using the `IAttributesof` of `MyCustomView`

```
public class MyCustomView : MvxRelativeLayout
{

    private MvxSpinner _spinner;
    private TextView _errorTxt;

    // A bunch of constructors

    public MyCustomView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapterWithChangedEvent adapter)
      : base(context, attrs, adapter) 
    {
        // Create an MvxSpinner with the attributes
        // IMvxAdapterWithChangedEvent is always null
        if(adapter == null){
            _spinner = new MvxSpinner(context, attrs);
        } else {
            _spinner = new MvxSpinner(context, attrs, adapter);
        }

        // Add View to the Layout
        AddView(_spinner);

        // Add a TextView
        _errorTxt = new TextView(context);
        _errorTxt.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        _errorTxt.SetTextAppearance(context, Android.Resource.Attribute.TextAppearanceLarge);
        _errorTxt.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        AddView(_errorTxt);
    }
}
```

The code above compiles and runs, but the MvxSpinner is not populated with according to the `local:MvxBind="ItemsSource StampTypes"`. When I remove the MyCustomView and use an MvxSpinner directly, all works as expected. Below is a screenshot of a normal MvxSpinner (which works like a charm) and the result of MyCustomView, where the MvxSpinner is not showing any items.

[image: Example, without binding]

At first, I thought that creating the MvxSpinner using the IAttributes would do the trick. However, the IMvxAdapterWithChangedEvent parameter is null, so I ran off to try to create the Adapter myself. What am I missing?

**Question:**
So, how can I programatically create an `MvxSpinner` using these `IAttributes`?

**NOTE:** I'm extending from RelativeLayout, because when I extend from MvxSpinner I cannot add a TextView to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do using `MvxRelativeLayout`.

`MvxRelativeLayout` is supplied to allow you to bind collections of items inside a relative layout - it's not designed for you to manually insert items.

You might be able to achieve something that matches your "reusable control" requirements by:

- using https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs - or by creating your own class similar to that control (based on RelativeLayout instead) - see the end of N=26 for more on this (http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/)
- using an Android `<include>` block.
- creating a custom Android control with C# properties which it forwards on to contained controls (see N=18 for an intro to custom controls)

Comment: I ended up creating a custom Android control. Usefull tutorial N=18